# How to set a custom cursor for a specific cursor function in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, text-cursor, custom-cursor

I want to set a custom cursor (.cur file) for a specific cursor function (cursor:text) on a website. So that when the cursor hovers over text, instead of the I-bar default text cursor, it is my custom cursor. Is there a way to define all text, or to set a custom cursor specifically for cursor:text ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```css
p, span{
cursor: url('path to custom cursor file or url or data url'), auto;
}
```

Make Sure to add all the text you have like a span or a p or h1 etc... AND make sure if you use a url it is 32x32 pixels or smaller or it will not work for example

```css
p{
  cursor: url('data:image/x-icon;base64,AAACAAEAICACAA8ADwAwAQAAFgAAACgAAAAgAAAAQAAAAAEAAQAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA///////////////////////////////////////8f////H////x////8f////H////x////8f////H///AAAf/wAAH/8AAB///x////8f////H////x////8f////H////x////8f/////////////////////////////////8='), auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

will make the cursor a black cursor, a good site to get cursors is cursor.cc